# How can some stretched derivative airplanes have longer range while most have less?

Tags: airbus-a320, boeing-737, range

On the one side [A321 neo has almost the same range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A320neo_family#Specifications) as the A320 neo (250 NM difference), and a LR version of A321 neo will have an even longer range. The same goes for  the [Dassault Falcon 7x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dassault_Falcon_7X) and the longer and longer-range Falcon 8x.

On the other side [Boeing 737 MAX line shows a clear tendency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_737_MAX#Specifications): the longer the fuselage the shorter the range. The same tendency can be [observed on most aircraft types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competition_between_Airbus_and_Boeing#Passenger_capacity_and_range_comparison).

I understand that fuel is generally in the wings which keep the same volume on a stretched derivative, but fuselage can accommodate fuel tanks and range can be a crucial point for aircraft. So why don't/can't aircraft manufacturers propose equivalent range stretched aircraft in general, as the A321 neo does?

Comment: My guess would be that the stretch is designed to accomplish a particular task. In some cases the task is to go farther, in others it's to carry more over the same (or shorter) range. Each manufacturer designs for the market they believe is emerging, to the niche they see as empty. For example, Boeing has ER & LR versions of the 777 which aren't any longer than the standard range, but have additional fuel tanks and increased MTOM.

Comment: Also compare the Falcon 7x and the longer and longer-range Falcon 8x

Comment: @CodyP and the infinite range Falcon 9 :p

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When aircraft are stretched, they usually just receive extra fuselage plugs on both sides of the wing: wing redesigns are incredibly expensive and take a long time. So the longer aircraft has a higher empty weight, and due to the unchanged wing design the fuel capacity remains the same - this reduces range. The aircraft is fuel limited. Conversely, if fuselage plugs are removed the same amount of fuel can take the aircraft further, as the B707-138 demonstrated, [Qantas' first jetliner.](https://qfom.com.au/2017/05/18/the-signifcance-of-our-boeing-707-138-vh-ebaxba/)

[image]

The A321NeoLR fixes the fuel limitation by adding extra fuel tanks in the cargo bays as [this article](https://leehamnews.com/2015/01/15/airbus-formally-launches-a321lr-we-look-behind-the-lr-to-see-whats-there/) explains, so that the aircraft now becomes weight limited. The extra fuel means that there can be less extra revenue from cargo. The B737-9 cannot follow suit, because it is has a shorter landing gear and has rotation limitations: from [this article:](https://leehamnews.com/2014/10/28/part-3-boeing-757-replacement-757-and-airbus-a321neolr-versus-clean-sheet-designs/)

> 737 MAX9 is not suitable for stretch to an international version, not because the wing is not good enough but because the MAX9 cannot bring the wing to an angle at take-off where it can work efficiently; the landing gear is too short.

[image]

The longer fuselage limits the rotation angle before a tailstrike occurs, so max. TO weight has a hard limit that cannot be managed by trading cargo weight for fuel weight. Above photo is from [this site](http://www.b737.org.uk/tailstrikes.htm#takeoff), which also contains a table with geometric angle limitations for the different 737 versions: the -9 has a tail strike pitch attitude of 10 deg, and has increased flap deflection of 25 deg to limit lift-off attitude to 6.8 degrees. A small variation in centre of gravity at a high TO weight can cause a tail strike.

Boeing has [launched the B737-10](https://www.flightglobal.com/news/articles/boeing-unveils-first-image-of-737-max-10x-434859/) which will address the rotation limit by a redesigned landing gear.

Comment: @ymb1 Thx, and the F70 and the B747SP.

Comment: True, but the -138 is more special though.

Comment: Just to comment regarding wings: Boeing 777-300ER is a "stretch" from 777-200 and has larger wing area. Same for MD-11. Same for A321 (despite what wikipedia says A321 seems to have larger wing, + additional winglets also increase the area)

Comment: @ParadigmPilot - A321 has different flaps, but same wing. 777-300ER/200LR/F have wing extensions (raked wingtips), but not new wings.

Comment: please @koyovis explain the link between "shorter landing gear and has rotation limitations" and the impossibility of "extra fuel tanks in the cargo bay" for the 737, this is unclear to me

Comment: @ymb1 - According to other opinions here https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-the-Airbus-A320-and-321-aircraft and here http://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=548239&p=7670407&hilit=yehudi+a321#p7670407A321 wing has slightly larger area and as you say different flaps. So I wouldn't call it the same wing. It has the same fuel capacity, but has slightly higher lift power due to wing area increase.

Comment: @ParadigmPilot the main structure and shape of the wing (profile, spars etc) remains unchanged. Tweaks such as increased flaps and winglets are added as much as possible within the limits of not having to alter the main wing geometry.

Comment: @ymb1 Aha, a dropped penny.

Comment: @Koyovis  - "…TO weight has a hard limit that cannot be managed by trading cargo weight for fuel weight." 
Why not? If you still have a headroom within Maximum Zero Fuel Mass, Max Take Off Mass and got some empty space in the fuel tanks - you can substitute passengers with fuel. This is what 737 BBJ does with its 5 or 6 belly tanks. It trades passengers for fuel to increase range. I don't think it's impossible to create the Long Range version of 737-10, but perhaps Boeing thinks it's not feasible.

Comment: @ParadigmPilot The BBJ is a lot shorter and does not have the rotation limit. The referenced sentence is in connection to the rotation limit. The BBJ has an easy life, weight-wise, with its low payload. The 737-10 is designed to match the range of the A321NeoER, by taking away the rotation limit through a re-design of the landing gear.

Comment: @Koyovis: Why not add fueltanks symmetrically to the front _and_ rear of the cargobay, thereby gaining extra fuel without shifting the 737M9's CG?

Comment: @Vikki With the same wing, extra TO weight will imply a higher rotational angle at TO - which is the variable that is limited in the B737-9

Comment: @Koyovis: Not if you increase VR to compensate for the increased weight, like you do to compensate for heavy cargo and passengers.  If the rotation limit isn't an issue for a particular weight of cargo, it also shouldn't be an issue if some of that cargo weight is traded 1:1 for extra fuel.