# what's the difference between an ER and an LR variant of the 777-200

Tags: boeing-777, range

I was curious about the difference between the 777-200 LR and the 777-200 ER

ER stands for extended range

LR stands for long range

What's the between them difference? Why have two variants which do the same thing?
And if one has a longer range than the other, why didn't they just use that one instead of doing both the ER and the LR?
And any performance differences?(Takeoff Distance, Landing distance)

Comment: Somewhat related-- https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/48466/34686 -- there are a *lot* of different ways to tweak a design and each choice is a trade-off of some kind--

Answer (score 2):

The Boeing 777-200**ER** is an upgrade of the original -200 variant with higher fuel capacity and MTOW (maximum takeoff weight). It is otherwise quite similar to the original variant. The 777-200**LR** is however part of the *second generation* of the 777 (along with the 777-300ER and 777-200F), which received a new wing with ~4m larger wingspan and is exclusively powered by the second generation [GE90](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Electric_GE90) engine (the -200ER has the option to use the PW4000, RR Trent 800 or first generation GE90). This gives the -200LR a significantly higher range:

|  | 777-200ER | 777-200LR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Introduced | 1997 | 2006 |
| Wingspan | 60.93 m | 64.8 m |
| MTOW | 297 550 kg | 347 815 kg |
| Max. Fuel | 137 460 kg | 145 538 kg |
| Range | 7065 NM | 8555 NM |

<sup>(source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_777#Specifications))</sup>

This makes the -200LR suitable for ultra-long haul flights, while the -200ER is more commonly used for shorter long haul flights:

> The B-market 777-200ER ("ER" for Extended Range), originally known as the 777-200IGW (increased gross weight), has additional fuel capacity and an increased MTOW enabling transoceanic routes. [...] As of 2018, 338 examples of the -200ER are in airline service. It competed with the A340-300. Boeing proposes the 787-10 to replace it. [...]
>
> The 777-200LR ("LR" for Long Range), the C-market model, entered service in 2006 as one of the longest-range commercial airliners. Boeing nicknamed it Worldliner as it can connect almost any two airports in the world, although it is still subject to ETOPS restrictions. It holds the world record for the longest nonstop flight by a commercial airliner. [...] The -200LR was intended for ultra long-haul routes such as Los Angeles to Singapore. [...] Airlines operated 50 of the -200LR variant as of 2018. [...] The closest competing aircraft from Airbus are the discontinued A340-500HGW and the current A350-900ULR.

<sup>([Wikipedia: Boeing 777](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_777#777-200ER))</sup>

The [Boeing 777X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_777X) will be the replacement for the 777-200LR and -300ER.

Comment: Had a pilot on the jumpseat years ago who had just finished the 777 type rating course at Boeing, who would soon be flying it for an airline. Asked him about it; he gushed about it being a wonderful airplane; it's only problem: "it holds *waaaay* too much gas!"